# Ajax & Jquery form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm about to pull the hair out of my head with this one.

I'm sure the problem is simple, I'm new to Ajax with Jquery and I'm just overlooking something. But Man this is annoying. Every time the form is submitted, the page refreshes and `.ajax` throws `error:`. What could be causing this? I know I'm getting my form values to the Jquery for sure. And `newcomment.php` is working. I can post regular forms to it, but not with jquery.

```
function postPhotoComment() {

    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var album = $("#album").val();
    var photo = $("#photo").val();
    var dataString = "comment="+comment+"&album="+album+"&photo="+photo;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/actions/photo-gallery/newcomment.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            alert("Posted!");
        }
            error: function(res) {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    })  
}
```

EDIT: Here's my html form:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Post Comment..."></textarea>
    <input id="album" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$a"?>"/>
    <input id="photo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$p.$ext"?>"/><br/>
    <button id="photo-comment-submit" onclick="postPhotoComment()">Post</button>
</form>
```

I also noticed that if I give the inputs `name`s, Chrome puts them into the url bar like `GET` variables. And after every page refresh, it adds the `?` at the end of the url. So, it seems like its trying to submit the form regularly.

Comment: How are you triggering the ajax call, and what it is in the error response (try using `console.log(res)` and checking the console?

Comment: Show the code for running the postPhotoComment() function. Submitting a form the regular way will refresh the page, and unless you have prevented the default action of your submit function, you probably submit the form both the regular way and with ajax, causing the page to refresh.

Comment: @Tyrsius postPhotoComment() is simply triggered with an onclick="".

Comment: @RyanSmith Then as others have stated, your form will still try to perform the default action of submitting non-ajax style. You need to return false from your function, or `preventDefault`

Comment: @Tyrsius It's definitely preforming the default action, but even after returning false, and preventDefault, I still get the same result.

Comment: @RyanSmith, your missing a comma after your success closing bracket. Might be nothing, but if you tried those I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Tyrsius Yeah the comma is in the actual markup.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments for my answer, bind the event to an actual submit button, or the `onsubmit` event of the form.

Comment: See my edit, or check out http://jsfiddle.net/wXrAU/ <-- the example works, if your code looks **exactly** like this and does not work, the problem is not related to the details in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If the function where you're calling the AJAX form submission code is the `onSubmit` method of the form, you'll need to stop the default action from happening -- that is, you want to stop normal submission.

To accomplish this, use the `preventDefault` method of the `event` object:

```
function postPhotoComment(evnt) {
    evnt.preventDefault();

    // existing code continues...

}
```

You may also return `false` from your event, but be aware that doing so has different effects in different browsers, and that it is not as explicit or reliable as calling `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` directly.

**Edit**
Also, the error handler is probably getting called because your code initiates the XHR request, but when the browser starts the default action (submitting the form), it cancels any pending XHR requests. This is causing the error handler to be triggered.

**Edit 2** I have created a jsFiddle with a working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/wXrAU/

**Documentation**

- `event.preventDefault` method on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: It's definitely preforming the default action, but even after returning false, and preventDefault, I still get the same result.

Comment: @RyanSmith Can you set up a jsFiddle so we can see it reproduced? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The post part isn't important, it's the javascript I'm interested in. Off the cuff, though, if you're binding the event to the `onclick` for the submit button, you should try placing it instead on the `onsubmit` event for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Are you returning false to stop the browsers default action?

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize(); // shortcut

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/actions/photo-gallery/newcomment.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            alert("Posted!");
        }
        error: function(res) {
             alert("Error!");
        }
    });

  return false;// cancels the default action
});
```

Comment: The error callback is triggered because as the browser starts to navigate off the page (to submit the form), it cancels any outstanding XHR requests. The cancellation of the request is treated as an error by jQuery, so the error handler is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `return false;` to the form when submitting, otherwise it will still submit as a "normal" form without using Ajax and reload the page.

EDIT: After reading the comments I think that this would be most appropriate for you:
`<form action="url.php" onsubmit="return false;"></form>`

jsFiddle with appropriate code: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/ZVgNv/

The PHP messes things up a little, but it works.

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to put the return. Aron.Duby has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this by simply removing the `<form>` tags. I didn't need them anyways. But everything seems to work now.

Comment: I see. Removing the form tags is one possible approach because you've removed the possibility of the form submitting without javascript. Effective, but not in keeping with progressive enhancement. It might not matter (the feature depends on javascript), but I suggest you pursue the actual problem for your own information, at least. Again, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/wXrAU/

Answer (score -4):

Make sure you write a valid, HTTP-accessible url instead of just a path to a script, e.g.

```
function postPhotoComment() {

    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var album = $("#album").val();
    var photo = $("#photo").val();
    var dataString = "comment="+comment+"&album="+album+"&photo="+photo;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yoursite.com/whatever/newcomment.php", // here
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            alert("Posted!");
        }
            error: function(res) {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    })  
}
```

Because JavaScript is a client-side language. It knows nothing about your filesystem structure or anything of that kind. And AJAX request is based on HTTP protocol.

Comment: @Tyrsius but who knows that the one stated is accessible?

Comment: Even if its not accessible, the URL being relative instead of absolute would not be the issue. Your answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Tyrsius I've fixed it before any comments so that nothing is here about absolute/relative paths.

Comment: dude it still points to the url being the issue, even now. I would advise you to delete this.

Comment: @Tyrsius no. Any possible reason is still a reason.

Comment: Ok man. The community obviously disagrees, and so do I. This answer is incorrect, 100%.